# How do I recompile Chocolatey virtual packages?

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget, chocolatey

I'm reading the tutorial on [recompiling packages](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-recompile-packages) so I can use them in my own repo, but when I get to this part:

> Next, open tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1.
>
> ```
> Install-ChocolateyZipPackage 'notepadplusplus.commandline' 'https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/6.x/6.8.7/npp.6.8.7.bin.zip' "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
> ```

All I see in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file is this:

```
#Install-VirtualPackage 'notepadplusplus.commandline' 'notepadplusplus.install'
```

There is no URL. How do I locate the URL this package goes to, to download the software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb and say that you have used this package:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/notepadplusplus

As you have been following the step in the article.

The article wants you to use this package:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/notepadplusplus.commandline

The first is what we refer to as a meta, or virtual package, in that it ONLY takes a dependency on another package.  As a result, there is nothing in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file.

If you go through the same process for the package that I linked to, you should see the URL that you need to change.

Comment: So how do virtualpackages work? I'm confused, I didn't see an installer anywhere in the package nor did I see an external URL. Where does it get the package from?

Comment: Scroll down on the package page until you hit the Dependencies section.  Here you will see a link to this package: https://chocolatey.org/packages/notepadplusplus.install which does contain the download URL's etc.  When installing a virtual/meta package, the dependencies are also installed.

Comment: So then virtual packages are sort of extended .install packages and can't exist without them?

Comment: In a way, yes.  In order to have a virtual/meta package, there must be another package that does the actual install.  Have a look here: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/ChocolateyFAQs#what-is-the-difference-between-packages-named-install-ie-autohotkeyinstall-portable-ie-autohotkeyportable-and--ie-autohotkey for more information on this.